# How to locate Spacy span from string range?

Tags: python, regex, nlp, spacy

I study natural language processing with spaCy and decided to write a pipe that will identify addresses like Dr, Mr, Mrs followed by names as person recognised entity. In the process, I decided to use regular expressions to identify the prefix part, and I found out that whenever I search RE pattern, it returns me the indexes in the whole source text. My task is to extract the addressed names and add them as `Span` objects, however the constructor demands me to pass a `Doc` object range.

Is it possible to locate the span in doc for a string position? I could have enumerated through every span individually storing the index as a separate variable and search the regular expression in it, and I will be satisfied with this solution, however is it possible to either translate string position to a span it belongs to or create spans for newly recognised entities in a different way?

```py
import re
import spacy as sp
from spacy.tokens import Doc, Span
from spacy.language import Language
english = sp.load('en_core_web_sm') #Load the English language model
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    source = f.read() #Text used from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocolate

@Language.component("addresses")
def searchNames(doc: Doc) -> Doc:
    """Searches for names in the text marked with addressing and adds them to the named entities."""
    #The pattern expression searches for names with addresses Mr., Mrs., Ms., Dr., Prof., etc.
    pattern = re.compile(r"(P|M|D)(r|s)(s|.)?") #(f|.)?\s[A-Z][a-z]+
    matches = [(match.start(), match.end()) for match in pattern.finditer(doc.text)]
    #Resolve the index error.
    #Add the names to the named entities.
    names = [Span(doc, start, end, "PERSON") for start, end in matches]
    doc.ents = tuple(list(doc.ents) + names)
    return doc

english.add_pipe("addresses")
chocolate = english(source)
for entity in chocolate.ents:
    if entity.label_ == "PERSON":
        print(entity.text, entity.label_)
```

Comment: Let me see if I understood your requirement with a quick example: If `sentence="I love Python"`, you want, say, a function `span_getter`, where `my_span = span_getter(sentence[2:6])  # my_span = 1`? Is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`Doc.char_span`](https://spacy.io/api/doc/#char_span).

```
doc = nlp("I like New York")
span = doc.char_span(7, 15, label="GPE")
assert span.text == "New York"
```

Also be sure to check the return value, as if your indices don't line up with token boundaries it will return `None`.